# R Shiny: Deselecting layers in Leaflet with ShinyWidget pickerInput

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I'm using ShinyWidget's pickerInput feature to allow users to select multiple layers (spatial data) to display in Leaflet. Checking multiple boxes displays the layers as desired, however, I'm unable to hide/deselect the layer after unchecking the box in the input menu.

Key code in my app.R script:

```
tn_data <- c("Rail"="rail1", "Airports"="airports1", "Ferries"="ferries1")

pickerInput(inputId = "pickv", label = "Transportation", choices = tn_data, multiple = TRUE),

rail_vn <- readOGR(dsn = "./geospatial_files/osm", layer = "gis.osm_railways_free_1")

server <- function(input, output, session) {

observeEvent(input$pickv, {
  if (input$pickv == "rail1"){  # this diplays just the rail layer
  proxy <- leafletProxy("map")
  proxy %>% addPolylines(data=rail_vn, weight = 2, group = "railv", color = "#7f0000")}
  else {proxy %>% clearGroup("railv")} # this does not work, unable to deselect/hide layer in Leaeflet
 }
)
```

Previously, when I used checkboxInput I was able to deselect the layer from Leaflet using the clearGroup function, but this does not work using pickerInput.

Any suggestions would be welcome, as I haven't been able to find any similar examples where pickerInput is used with Leaflet.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should define the proxy outside of the if then, so that is also available on the else.

```
observeEvent(input$pickv, {
  proxy <- leafletProxy("map")
  if (input$pickv == "rail1"){  # this diplays just the rail layer
     proxy %>% addPolylines(data=rail_vn, weight = 2, group = "railv", color = "#7f0000")}
  else {
        proxy %>% clearGroup("railv")} # this does not work, unable to deselect/hide layer in Leaeflet
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm still unable to deselect the layer. I've also tried using proxy %>% clearShapes()

Comment: I notice that if I uncheck the box with the displayed layer (rail1) and then select another layer the rail1 layer is removed from display. It seems that unchecking the box on its own is not being detected by observeEvent.